# Accessing Visual Studio Database Project Schema Programatically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-schema, database-project

I'm trying to find a way to access the schema of a database project programatically from within Visual Studio 2010.

For example, if I have a solution containing a SQL Server Database Project which defines tables, views etc, and Visual Studio displays those objects within the schema view, I'd like to be able to enumerate the objects in the schema view.

Can anyone provide some tips or a link? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833285.aspx). The "Create Custom Features for Database Projects" part is probably relevant for you.